# Loop and add one to the range

Tags: excel, vba

I have this workbook with 2 sheets, the first sheet has a list of information and the second sheet is a form. I need to go through each line on the first sheet and put that information into the form, and save that sheet as a new workbook and be named from a certain cell. I basically have it all, I just need to put it in a loop and add one to the range every time it loops. Here is what I got, is there a easy way to make it loop and add one to the range. Thanks.

```
Sub Range_Copy()

   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J2").Copy Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("K3:O3")
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K2").Copy Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("E3:H3")
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Copy Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:O1")
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Copy Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("E29:F29")
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Copy Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("G29:H29")
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Copy Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("D7:O7")
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Copy Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("L8:O8")
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Copy Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("D8:G8")
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G2").Copy Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("D9:O9")
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2").Copy Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("D6:O6")
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I2").Copy Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A48:O48")

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   ActiveSheet.Select
   ActiveSheet.Copy
   ThisFile = Range("A1").Value
   ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="H:\Intern Work\Server List\Server Form List\" & 
   ThisFile & ".xlsx"
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Loop through what? Add `1` to which range? Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Loop through the entire VBA code. Currently this code does exactly what I want it to do for one line. I need to make it loop and add one to first range list, the j2, k2, a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, g2,h2, i2. When It loops I need it to add one and run the entire code and repeat 600 times.

Comment: @MatthewValdez But what do you want to do with it after you iterate once? You're going to keep overwriting your same saved file because you never change the value of `A1`, unless that's a formula linked to something else - but are you really planning on saving 600 individual documents?

Comment: add one being J3 K3 etc? And copying to plus one destination  i.e. K4:04 E4:H4 etc? You wouldn't use a loop for that.

Comment: @dwirony The file is being saved as the value that is in A1 on the second sheet, as the loop increases the range, A1 will be changing value each time and being saved as something different.

Comment: What is repeating 600 times?

Comment: @MatthewValdez So I'm assuming your `ActiveSheet` is `Worksheets("Sheet4")`? You don't specify which sheet you're getting your value from for `ThisFile`.

Comment: @qharr, I just need to add one to the range on sheet1 and not sheet 4. Currently it is grabbing information from Sheet 1 line 2 and putting it on Sheet 4 and saving it as a new work book. I need it to repeat and increment the range by one  for sheet 1and repeat since I have 600 lines of information.

Comment: @Davesexcel Nothing is, I need it to add one to range on sheet 1, and repeat the entire vba code 600 times.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this is what you're looking for, however I'm not sure if you're going to hit any snags when trying to save 600 individual files -

```
Sub Range_Copy()

Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet, newwb As Workbook

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For i = 2 To lastrow

    sht2.Range("A1:O1").Value = sht.Range("A" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("E29:F29").Value = sht.Range("B" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("G29:H29").Value = sht.Range("C" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("D7:O7").Value = sht.Range("D" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("L8:O8").Value = sht.Range("E" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("D8:G8").Value = sht.Range("F" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("D9:O9").Value = sht.Range("G" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("D6:O6").Value = sht.Range("H" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("A48:O48").Value = sht.Range("I" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("K3:O3").Value = sht.Range("J" & i).Value
    sht2.Range("E3:H3").Value = sht.Range("K" & i).Value

    Set newwb = Workbooks.Add
    sht2.Copy Before:=newwb.Sheets(1)
    newwb.SaveAs Filename:="H:\Intern Work\Server List\Server Form List\" & sht2.Range("A1").Value & ".xlsx"
    newwb.Close False

Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: i think it should probably be closing those newly saved files as well tbh

Comment: Ok I appreciate the help. That looks like what I want, but I am getting an error at the part of saving, but I think I may be able to figure it out.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Hmm when I tested it I didn't need to close any files, they were saved in the background.

Comment: Interesting! Should've made my own test file for this, then. I just didn't want OP to have 600+ instances of excel open haha

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Yeah I thought about that as well - the thing is , `ActiveSheet.SaveAs` is still just renaming the entire workbook and keeping all the worksheets - I'm wondering if OP just wanted the individual worksheet saved as the new title...

Comment: @dwirony. Run-time error'1004': This extension can not be used with the selected file type. Change the file extension in the File name text box or select a different file type by changing the Save as type.

Comment: @MatthewValdez What is in `Range("A1")` on Sheet4?

Comment: It has something to do with the xlsx format. I was able to do it previously, but now I cannot. I can change it to xls and it will run perfectly.

Comment: I can't load your `imgur` picture, but it might have something to do with your naming standard as well.

Comment: Correction, not perfectly. It is saving the entire workbook, just need to make it where it only saves sheet4 and not sheet1.

Comment: @dwirony Ok I have almost everything perfect, managed to get it to save as a .xlsx. The only thing I need to try to figure out is when it saves only sheet4 and not sheet1.

Comment: @dwirony I appreciate all the help, figured it out about 10mins ago. The reason I had the issue saving as xlsx was because I needed to run it in an excel doc that isn't macro enabled. Then for the saving, I needed to select activesheet and that fixed all my issues.